# Change all navigations links on hover of one

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm trying to replica the navigation menu from this [website](https://webflow.com). I've managed to it working to a certain extent, but can't make the service link when hovered to stay the same colour and all of the other to change.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.nav a {
  color: #000;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: fit-content;
}

.nav ul:hover a{
  color: #eee !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #333;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 35px 0 0;
}

.three:hover>.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1
}

.sub-menu {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: #333;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="one">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="two">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="three">
        <a class="">Services</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">

          <div class="col-1-4"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="four">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I've changed the link colours on hover of the unordered list which is probably not the best way of trying to get this to work. Please, could someone advise me on the best method to fix this?

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to do. Can you elaborate a bit? Do you want the dropdown? I can't see any hovers on the example site changing other navigation

Comment: So when I hover over the 'service' link it should stay the same colour and all the others change colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close -- you have to remove the `!important` from the rule affecting `.nav ul:hover a` as this is overriding the rule that will ensure the hovered item is a different color than the rest:

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.nav a {
  color: #000;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: fit-content;
}

.nav ul:hover a{
  color: #eee;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #333;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 35px 0 0;
}

.three:hover>.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1
}

.sub-menu {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: #333;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="one">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="two">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="three">
        <a class="">Services</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">

          <div class="col-1-4"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="four">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a good resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) on how `!important` affects other rules on the page.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Just one more thing. The hovers taking place on the ul rather than when I hover the link, how can I fix that?

Comment: Your best bet is to make sure the `ul` is only as small as you want it to be so that the hover effect does not happen when hovering to the left or to the right of the nav bar. Then, you can make sure that the hover effect always applies to an `li` by changing the `a` styles to target the `li` instead of the underlying `a`. See this jsfiddle with working example: https://jsfiddle.net/j8dmu6p9/2/